# How long Prometheus timeseries last without and update

Tags: time-series, prometheus

If I send a gauge to Prometheus then the payload has a timestamp and a value like:

> metric_name {label="value"} 2.0 16239938546837

If I query it on Prometheus I can see a continous line. Without sending a payload for the same metric the line stops. Sending the same metric after some minutes I get another continous line, but it is not connected with the old line.

Is this fixed in Prometheus how long a timeseries last without getting an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two questions here :

**1. How long does prometheus keeps the data ?**

This depends on the configuration you have for your storage. By default, on local storage, prometheus have a retention of 15days. You can find out more [in the documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/). You can also change this value with this option : `--storage.tsdb.retention.time`

**2. When will I have a "hole" in my graph ?**

The line you see on a graph is made by joining each point from each scrape. Those scrape are done regularly based on the `scrape_interval` value you have in your **scrape_config**. So basically, if you have no data during one scrape, then you'll have a hole.
So there is no definitive answer, this depends essentially on your `scrape_interval`.

Note that if you're using a function that evaluate metrics for a certain amount of time, then missing one scrape will not alter your graph. For example, using a `rate[5m]` will not alter your graph if you scrape every 1m (as you'll have 4 other samples to do the rate).

Answer (score 5):

I think the first answer by Marc is in a different context.

Any timeseries in prometheus goes stale in 5m by default if the collection stops - https://www.robustperception.io/staleness-and-promql. In other words, the line stops on graph (or grafana).

So if you resume the metrics collection again within 5 minutes, then it will connect the line by default. But if there is no collection for more than 5 minutes then it will show a disconnect on the graph. You can tweak that on Grafana to ignore drops but that not ideal in some cases as you do want to see when the collection stopped instead of giving the false impression that there was continuous collection. Alternatively, you can avoid the disconnect using some functions like `avg_over_time(metric_name[10m])` as needed.

Comment: There is also `last_over_time(m[d])` function in Prometheus, which allows removing gaps with the duration up to `d` - https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time