# client_golang prometheus remove gauge from gaugevec

Tags: go, prometheus

When deleting a gauge from a gaugevec, the gauge value is still presented on the graph as the value it was last set to.  It seems to expire after 5 minutes.  Is there a way to immediately discontinue the gauge data upon deletion?  Setting the value to 0 retains the stale gauges, which accumulate over time, without a TTL.

Example:
gaugeVec.Delete(labels) // does not remove the gauge immediately.

Comment: What version of Prometheus server are you using? Prometheus version 2 inserts a stale marker when a time series disappears from a scrape

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021117/how-long-prometheus-timeseries-last-without-and-update
The timer for 5 minutes, as far as I know, is an internal thing and not tunable. But it never caused problems to me, so perhaps there is a better way to do what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the server pulls data every 5 minutes and this is the time it will take for prometheous server to reflect. Deleting or unregistering a metric will not push data to prometheus server, this will have to be picked up on next scrape.

There are ways to [push metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) to promeheus, depending how badly you need this to happen.